# Resharper does not navigate to external sources despite pdb files present

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, pdb-files

- My solution uses classes from .dlls generated by my other solutions
- .dll where generated in debug mode on the same machine, pdb files are present
- **steeping into those external sources during debugging works, so I am assuming pdb files are correct**
- pdp files are in the same directory as .dlls
- In R# settings I have "Navigation to Sources" selected and "Use debug information for navigation checked"
- VS2012 Pro and R# 8.02 Full

It drives me crazy, how come such crucial thing, that is provided out-of-the-box in every common free IDE for Java, is impossible to get to work in C# using tools for hundreds of bucks...

Comment: Can you post the file you see when you click ReSharper -> Options -> External Sources -> Show support information? (Perhaps paste as a gist or something). Make sure you take a look through before you post - there will be information about your project in there - filenames, paths, pdb symbols, etc. Remove anything you're not happy sharing publicly.

Comment: I put it [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f3cb4f4106b82a80ad6). Removed most entries from pdbServiceImpl as there were plenty of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the dump in [the gist you posted](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f3cb4f4106b82a80ad6), the first issue I can see is the empty section for `PdbCacheManagerImpl`. This is the list of pdbs that ReSharper knows about. This shouldn't be empty. There is [a known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-406276) that can cause this to be empty. Try closing and reopening the solution to see if that kicks it off again.

Similarly, the assemblies in your `PdbServiceImpl` section don't include any information about pdbs. I think this is related to the `PdbCacheManagerImpl` - since ReSharper doesn't know about the pdb files, it doesn't get listed here. When it's working, it should show the pdb file related to the assembly, plus a list of all symbols in the pdb, and the file(s) they map to.

(I can recreate this by creating a new solution - the dump shows nothing in this section. Close and reopen and it shows known dlls, with flags to say if they support source servers and whether they contain a map between symbols (types) and source files. After closing and reopening, I can download and see source for e.g. `Console.WriteLine`, and the `PdbServiceImpl` has an entry for `System.Console` in the mscorlib pdb)

Secondly, you don't have "Allow downloading from remote locations" enabled in your options. This will only affect you for downloading pdb files from symbol servers, it shouldn't stop things working with pdbs next to dlls. You will need it enabled to navigate to source of `Console.WriteLine`, though.

So, unfortunately, my advice right now is to close and reopen the solution, and try again. You might be hitting the known bug, and the only way to work around this is to close and reopen. Once you've reopened, try navigating again, and try dumping the support information again - you should see more pdbs in the `PdbCacheManagerImpl` and a list of known symbols in the `PdbServiceImpl` section.

Comment: Huh, looks like you were right, one day later I suddenly was able to navigate to SOME of the external source, now it seems to work for most of them. Well, not the best user experience I had so far, but at least it sorta works I guess..

Comment: I forgot to link to the bug - it's just been fixed, and should be part of 8.2, available in the next EAP build: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-406276. With the fix, it should be much more reliable about downloading the pdb, and using the symbols declared in it

Comment: I've updated to 8.2 and seems to be still working.. however now I have completely opposite issue - navigating to external soures within IDE works, but I am unable to step inside the very same file during debugging ("Stepping over method without symbols "). Can be unrelated to Resharper since in the meantime we change project structure, but still... how can people work liket that :/

Afetr my C#/VS expieriences I will think twice before complaining about Java or Eclipse again.

Comment: i have been working with r#2016 and its the same. if i built the referenced libraries, everything works fine, if someone else built them last, i cannot navigate to these libs.