# ReSharper PdbNavigator No debugging information found on symbol servers

Tags: resharper, nuget, debug-symbols, pdb-files

We have TeamCity setup to create a NuGet package and a symbol source package for an internal component. The symbol source packages correctly contains the dll's, pdb's and source code.

Once TeamCity has created the packages, they are published to our NuGet / SymbolSource server.

In ReSharper I have configured 'External Sources' to be 'Navigation to Sources'. The NuGet package has been added to a project, but when navigating to sources, the ReSharper output shows this error:

> PdbNavigator: Downloader: 
>   `http://symbolserver/SymbolSource/WinDbg/pdb`::MyLib.dll::3A9F94B78ED243228DC8CB98D71483D615
>   -> Ok (cached) 
>   PdbNavigator: No debugging information found on symbol servers for MyLib, Version=3.2.5123.12213, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=3111e51d1da2afdf

The PDB is being successfully pulled down, but ReSharper is unable to step into the sources. When a debugger is attached, source files can be correctly stepped into so I assume this is a ReSharper configuration issue. How can I get 'Navigate to > Sources from symbol files' to work in ReSharper?

UPDATE:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-405000

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in ReSharper 8 that can cause it to download the pdb, but then not process it, so it doesn't see the symbols and so can't navigate to the source. This mostly manifests in a new project (or at least, the easiest way to recreate it is with a new project). Closing and reopening the solution uses causes the navigation to succeed, because ReSharper now knows about the pdb file, can find the symbols and load the source.

Here's the bug details: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-406276. It's just been fixed and will be included in the next 8.2 EAP and will be part of the 8.2 release.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I don't think this is my issue. The bug says it affects 8.2 EAP, but I am running the latest stable version (8.1.23.546). It doesn't seem to matter how many times I restart VS or the machine I can't get it to load.

Comment: It also affects 8.1, but I only tested on 8.2. Try viewing the support information at ReSharper -> Options -> External Sources. There's a ton of info. See this answer for some hints at what to look for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153210/resharper-does-not-navigate-to-external-sources-despite-pdb-files-present/22175223#22175223

Comment: Just tested on ReSharper 8.2 EAP and unfortunately the issue persists. Thanks for your recommendation though.

Comment: Don't give up on 8.2 yet - the fix hasn't made it to the public release. Should be in the next one.

Comment: Just tested on 8.2.0.1583-EAP and the issue is still present. I have updated the question to contain a link to the bug on the JetBrains site. Currently no fixes/workarounds are listed.

Comment: Yeah, I've just tested too, and it's not fixed. I've added a new comment on the related issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-406276. Does your navigation work if you close and reopen the solution in the same VS session?

Comment: Still experienced this with Resharper 9, reopening the solution did it.

Comment: Still seeing this with Resharper 9.1

Comment: Are you sure this is a bug in ReSharper, and not just that the .pdb files aren't available? If you've got e.g. VS2015 preview installed, you'll be using a preview version of .net 4.6, which doesn't have symbols ready, AFAIK. Try running Fiddler and looking at the network traffic while trying to download the symbols. If you get a 404, it's not ReSharper's fault. If it downloads symbols, it's a bug in ReSharper, and repro steps would be very much appreciated.