# Proget symbol server: Downloads pdb but says no debugging symbols found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget-server, proget

So I'm on the latest version - Proget 3.0.3 build 1

Whatever I do, I cannot get Proget to act as a symbol server. not sure if this is VS2012/Proget or both.
To review:

1. Package and symbols have been uploaded to Proget manually. Verified that Proget reports that symbols are available on the package page.
2. Package Id matches what I have on the referenced DLL.
3. In the output window, I see

`PdbNavigator: Downloader: http://myserver/symbols/default/CQRS.Engine.pdb/9C8207DD2A6443DCB1D717C237949F317/CQRS.Engine.pdb -> ok, 91.5 KB
    PdbNavigator: No debugging information found on symbol servers for CQRS.Engine, Version=2.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

So it is downloading the .pdb file but then errors out? Visiting the link from the output window downloads the pdb as well.

I don't see any indexing errors or otherwise on Proget server - so I'm assuming this is visual studio more than proget.

**UPDATE 1**
So after digging further -  I was able to get a log that indicates that PDB is okay but then the source download fails. My proget server is behind a reverse proxy - so that's definitely the reason for the 'localhost:81' in the url. However, I suspect that it still won't work otherwise since if I replace that with my server name, I still get a 404 error.

Does anyone have Proget working properly behind a reverse proxy?

```
PdbNavigator: Searching for 'CQRS.Engine.DataSerializer' type sources in C:\Users\RAGHUR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\CQRS.Engine.pdb\9C8207DD2A6443DCB1D717C237949F317\CQRS.Engine.pdb
PdbNavigator: Downloader: http://localhost:81/source-files/default/CQRS.Engine/2.2.3/CQRS.Engine/DataSerializer.cs -> Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:81
PdbNavigator: No sources found in debugging information for 'CQRS.Engine.DataSerializer' in assembly 'CQRS.Engine, Version=2.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

**UPDATE 2** looks like this might be a Resharper issue [ReSharper PdbNavigator No debugging information found on symbol servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251417/resharper-pdbnavigator-no-debugging-information-found-on-symbol-servers)

Comment: If the file can be downloaded from the URL then it doesn't appear to be on the ProGet side. Perhaps there is a version mismatch between what's loaded for your project and the one it's requesting? Try clearing the symbol cache on your machine and see if that helps.

Comment: @JohnRasch - yeah - have been trying a few things. I compared the guids embedded (the 9C8207...)one and that matches up. My guess now is that it finds the .pdb but cannot find the sources for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this on our nuget packages and Proget.  In our case, we were building nuget packages that had the sources in a folder called src (but we also have a 'src' folder in our repo) so it led to a path that looked (in the package) like src/src/...

I found that if I set the "Advanced" settings for the navigation in resharper, and tell it to remap src/src -> src, then it starts working.

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

So it did turn out to be Resharper 7.1.x. Apparently, the issue is still open. During debugging, symbols download works as expected.